# Why is $f$ differentiable on each straight line through the origin because on the straight line $y = m x$, it has the value $\frac{m x}{m^2 + x^2}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

Let $f(0, 0) := 0$ and $f(x, y) := \frac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2}$ for $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$.

There are the following sentences in this book:

> "The function $f$ is particularly interesting. It is differentiable (and hence continuous) on each straight line through the origin. (In fact, on the straight line $y = m x$, it has the value $\frac{m x}{m^2 + x^2}$.)

But I cannot understand the above sentences.
Why is $f$ differentiable at any point on each straight line through the origin because on the straight line $y = m x$, it has the value $\frac{m x}{m^2 + x^2}$?

By the way, I know $f$ is differentiable at any point on each straight line through the origin except the origin because $f$ is a $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0, 0)\}$.

Maybe Munkres just wanted to say that all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at any point on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read that as “the restriction of $f$ to a straight line through the origin is differentiable at each point on the line.” That is, if you view the restriction of $f$ to a line through the origin as a function $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, then $\phi$ is differentiable everywhere.

The point of this example is that differentiability of multi-variable functions is a rather strong condition: even having all of its directional derivatives exist isn’t sufficient for a function to be differentiable. Just as with limits, you have to consider *all* paths that lead to the point. Looking only along straight lines isn’t enough.

Comment: $u := (1, m)^T$ and $t := x$?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the value of the function on the line $y = mx$, you just plug in that value of $y$. So, you get a new function of a single variable:
$$f_m(x) := f(x,mx) = \frac{x^2\cdot(mx)}{x^4+ m^2x^2}= \frac{mx}{x^2+ m^2}.$$
It is now easy to see that this function of $x$ is totally differentiable:
$$f'_m(x) = \frac{m(x^2+m^2) - mx(2x)}{(x^2+m^2)^2} = \frac{m^3 - mx^2}{(x^2+m^2)^2},$$
which is well defined on $\mathbb R$.

Notice that this new function $f_m$ is also differentiable (and hence continuous) at the origin, even though $f$ wasn't.

Comment: I guess "differentiable" means "totally differentiable" in the above sentences.

Comment: Yes, I changed that for clarity. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Maybe Munkres wanted to say that all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much.